# How can I play MineCraft PE with a Fire and IPhone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to play Minecraft PE with my son. I have the IPhone and he has a 2015 Kindle Fire. I have used a YouTube tutorial to try to figure it out. I put in the IP address, enables LAN game, etc., but when I try to start a game, it says "Cannot connect to world."

We are both connected to the same router. Do I have to monkey with the router's settings?

Answer (score 1):

Considering both iPhone and Kindle Fire uses the same version, you should probably allow the devices to connect each other, either through the devices or the router.

Also if the devices have mobile internet, please try disabling that too. I'm not sure if you can install a firewall to an iPhone or a Kindle Fire, but if you have one installed, please try disabling that too.